ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.wrappers'
I'm trying to use GridSearchCV for a machine learning classification task, however I keep getting an error with this line, any suggestions?
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

my tensorflow version is 2.16.1 and my keras version is 3.3.3
I've tried the following:
pip install scikeras

from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier

and gotten "ImportError: cannot import name '_deprecate_Xt_in_inverse_transform' from 'sklearn.utils.deprecation'"
Any help would be appreciated!

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.

if you use jupyter, you shold restart the kernel after install package.

Please try  by using these commands pip show scikit-learn , pip install --
upgrade scikit-learn and pip install --upgrade numpy scipy joblib. Let us
know if you are still facing the issue . Thank you.
